# Call generic controller

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have class `Menu` that is 'UICollectionView'. In that class I have a function called `showMenu()`

In the show menu function I finish everything and then I need to navigate to the controller based on the actions (Edit, ShowAll, etc). I try to do this by calling controller variable in the class. Like this: self.controller.navigateToAction(action: action)

```
class Menu: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    weak var controller: ViewController? //can we define this as generic?

    func showMenu(action: Action) {
      // some logic        
      // then I need to navigate to the function in the controller

      self.controller?.navigateToAction(action: action)
   }
}
```

From my controller I call this function as: (notice menu.controller = self). Please note I will have many viewcontrollers (homecontroller, summarycontroller, etc.)

```
class HomeController: UIViewController {

lazy var menuLauncher: Menu = {
        let menu = Menu()
        menu.controller = self
        menu.actions =  {
            return [
                Action(name: .Edit, imageName: "edit"),
                Action(name: .ViewAll, imageName: "view-all"),
                Action(name: .Cancel, imageName: "cancel")
            ]}()

        return menu
    }()

   func navigateToAction(action: action) {

    // based on action navigate to a certain viewcontroller(edit, viewall, etc)
    }

    // Cell delegate functions on button click    
    func launchSlider() {
         menuLauncher.showMenu()
    }
}
```

Is there a way in the Menu class I can define generic viewcontroller which I can define in the 'menuLancher' initialization, so I can pass that information to the Menu class, showMenu function from where I will call back the function in the calling ViewController?

I would need to access `navigateToAction` function in the calling `ViewController`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using protocols. Define some protocol that requires `func navigateToAction(action: Action)` method (also you can constraint the protocol to UIViewController)

```
protocol ActionNavigatable: UIViewController {

  func navigate(to action: Action)
}

...

final class HomeController: UIViewController, ActionNavigatable {

  func navigate(to action: Action) {

  }

...
```

Now in your `Menu` class you can refer to a `controller` as `ActionNavigatable`

Or, as an option, you can cast it:

```
(controller as? ActionNavigatable)?.navigate(to: action)
```

Comment: Thanks looks like I will use protocols. I don't think I can cast since there will be calls from many ViewControllers (Home, Settings, etc)